# How do I figure out what these ack signals mean?

Tags: i2c, analysis, logic-analyzer

I am trying to get the data from a rangefinder and an HT1621 LCD driver. I have set up a logic analyzer that uses an I2C analyzer. I am receiving all of these signals but frankly don't know where to go from here. Any idea on how to figure out what these mean or where the data is between all of this? Also, based on this datasheet for the LCD driver, how would I input the commands for the READ command, if at all possible?

https://datasheet.lcsc.com/lcsc/1811021420_Holtek-Semicon-HT1621B_C7873.pdf

[image: Small snippet of Info I have]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The display driver chip does not have an I2C interface and the captured data is not I2C even if you forcibly decoded it as I2C. Decoding the bus as I2C is rather useless as it is the wrong protocol, so the data or ACK/NAK are not meaningful in any way.

The data sheet says the chip has a 3-wire serial interface and there are diagrams how to read and write data.

To even capture data, you need four wires and ground, the chip select, data, read and write wires. That is very unusual protocol but as the Saleae software allows downloadable plugins, such a plugin may be available for directly decoding the bus protocol.

Comment: ok, appreciate it. I will try that once again because I believe I screwed up the first time that way, but you just confirmed it.